# All rails application logs being written to apache error log

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-12.04, ruby, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I've deployed a ruby on rails 4.0.3 application to a server that I've configured with the following likely relevant software:

- Ubuntu 12.04.4 x64 server
- Phusion Passenger 4.0.37
- Apache 2.2.22
- Ruby 2.0.0p353
- Rails 4.0.3 / Capistrano 2.15.5 / Rake 10.1.1

Everything with the app seems to be working properly, with the exception of the rails application logging.  My expectation is that everything application-specific should be written to the {Rails.root}/log/production.log file.  However, everything seems to be being written to /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Here's an excerpt from the apache error.log to show what I mean:

```
App 1495 stdout: Started GET "/" for 192.168.1.106 at 2014-03-08 17:26:04 -0500
App 1495 stdout: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
App 1495 stdout:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
App 1495 stdout:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.0ms)
App 1495 stdout:   Rendered home/_auth.html.erb (0.4ms)
App 1495 stdout:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
App 1495 stdout: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 5.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I find it interesting that the log/production.log even gets created, but nothing is being written to it.

Some things that I've looked into/verified:

- RAILS_ENV=production
- The {Rails.root}/config/environments/production.rb is set to all of the default values
- My apache/passenger setup is mostly default, with the exception of having to add a virtualhost entry for my app, like so:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80> 
>         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
>         DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/myapp/current/public 
>         RailsEnv production  
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

- Permissions across all of the files in the rails app, appear to be good - and in desperation I tried to grant '777' permission to the log/production.log, to no avail.

I'll be happy to provide any other application configuration information or environment details upon request.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately none yet.

Comment: Actually, I think this might have just been an issue with that version of rails.  I just deployed a new rails app that is built on 4.1.1 and it's writing the log/production.log.

Try upgrading your version of rails and see what happens.

FYI, I also upgraded a few other components, but the most major change was rails.  If it doesn't fix it for you, I'll provide specific versions for the other stuff in my environment.

Comment: I can confirm that upgrading to rails 4.1.1 solved the logs problem

Comment: In my case I face this problem on Rails 4.1.5. I upgraded to 4.1.6 without success.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. In my case a `#{Rails.root}/config.ru` included the line `use Rails::Rack::LogTailer`. This was causing all Rails logging to also be added to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Did removing/modifying that line work or did you have to update your version like the OP referenced?